# Amazon S3 downloads require key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of Amazon S3 files that I want to download from within my app. However, I don't want them to be public.

**Is there a way to require a key in the URL query in order to download the file? So far, I have not found documentation on this.**

Comment: Placing a key in the download URL is about the same as making a bucket with an obscure name. You can control access to content on S3 with an access control list.

Comment: ACL is very good option instead of using key.

Comment: @error2007s Can you explain?

Comment: Can you provide some details regarding your app on what platform it is built?

Comment: @error2007s iOS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as ["Presigned URLS"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Basically, you use the AWS SDK to generate a temporary URL, which includes some credentials that expire after a duration that you specify, and provide that to your end user.

Comment: Just what I needed! There is an iOS SDK that I will use for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your app runs.

If it runs on an ec2 instance, then ec2 instance runs with a certain role specified at creation (see "IAM role" in instance details). You can either configure that role to have full access to S3 or grant that role permissions to particular files in S3.

If your app runs outside of AWS. It's slightly more complicated as you need to configure credentials to be used. Don't know what you use to write your app, so below is a link to configuring go SDK. Others must be very similar. If my memory is correct, I just configured aws cli on my dev machine and that saved credentials in the right place for my app to use. To be fair, you can use this approach on an ec2 instance as well if you want, but I find IAM role approach easier there.

[Access Control List (ACL) Overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)

[Using an IAM Role to Grant Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html)

[SDK Configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/latest/v1/developerguide/configuring-sdk.title.html) It's for go language, but others will be very similar. See Specifying Credentials section.